# Exporting Data to a Specific Row in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am writing a bunch of data to an excel file and as of now the script I have exports all the data to every row from row 1 to row 36. Each row contains 15 columns worth of data as can be seen in the code below. I need to somehow send the data from the first city in the loop to row1, the data from the second city to row 3, the data from the third city to row 6, etc... I can't do something like

```
row = row + 2
```

because they need to be assigned to predetermined rows that are not evenly spaced.

This is the script that sends the data to excel:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook

import canada

cities = canada.getCities()

for c in cities :
        c.retrieveTemps()


## 
# writing to excel
##
file_name = 'fcst_hilo_TEST.xls'
new_file_name = 'fcst_hilo.xls'
row = 1


column_names = ["high0", "low1", "high1", "low2", "high2",
                "low3", "high3", "low4", "high4", "low5",
                "high5", "low6", "high6", "low7", "high7"]

workbook_file = None
try :
        # currently xlwt does not implement this option for xslx files
        workbook_file = open_workbook(file_name, formatting_info=True)
except :
        workbook_file = open_workbook(file_name)

workbook = copy(workbook_file)
sheet = workbook.get_sheet(0)

for row, city in enumerate(cities, start=1):
    for column, col_name in enumerate(column_names, start=2):
        sheet.write(row, column, getattr(city, col_name))

workbook.save(new_file_name)
```

I have 36 cities that are all listed in a separate script (below) This is part of 'canada', what is imported into the script above:

```
class city(object):
    def __init__(self, city_name, link) :
        self.name = city_name
        self.url = link
        self.high0 = 0
        self.high1 = 0
        self.high2 = 0
        self.high3 = 0
        self.high4 = 0
        self.high5 = 0
        self.high6 = 0
        self.high7 = 0
        self.low1 = 0
        self.low2 = 0
        self.low3 = 0
        self.low4 = 0
        self.low5 = 0
        self.low6 = 0
        self.low7 = 0

    def retrieveTemps(self) :
        filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)

        # get lines from result into array
        lines = filehandle.readlines()
        filehandle.close()

        # (for each) loop through each line in lines
        for line_number, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
            # find string, position otherwise position is -1
            position0 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date.strftime("%A")))
            position1 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date1.strftime("%A")))
            position2 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date2.strftime("%A")))
            position3 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date3.strftime("%A")))
            position4 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date4.strftime("%A")))
            position5 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date5.strftime("%A")))
            position6 = line.rfind('title="{}"'.format(date6.strftime("%A")))

            if position0 > 0 :
                self.high0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low1 = lines[line_number + 18].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

            if position1 > 0 :
                self.high1 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low2 = lines[line_number + 19].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

            if position2 > 0 :
                self.high2 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low3 = lines[line_number + 19].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

            if position3 > 0 :
                self.high3 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low4 = lines[line_number + 19].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

            if position4 > 0 :
                self.high4 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low5 = lines[line_number + 19].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

            if position5 > 0 :
                self.high5 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low6 = lines[line_number + 19].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.low7 = lines[line_number + 19].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

            if position6 > 0 :
                self.high6 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                self.high7 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
                break # done with loop, break out of it

    def getCities():
        return [
            #BRITISH COLUMBIA CITIES
            city('Prince George', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/bc-79_metric_e.html'),
            city('Kamloops', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/bc-45_metric_e.html'),
            city('Blue River', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/bc-22_metric_e.html'),

            # Alberta
            city('High Level', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-24_metric_e.html'),
            city('Peace River', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-25_metric_e.html'),
            city('Jasper', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-70_metric_e.html'),
            city('Edmonton', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-50_metric_e.html'),
            city('Calgary', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html'),

            #SASKATCHEWAN CITIES

            city('Biggar', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/sk-2_metric_e.html'),
            city('Saskatoon', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/sk-40_metric_e.html'),
            city('Melville', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/sk-8_metric_e.html'),
            city('Canora', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/sk-3_metric_e.html'),
            city('Yorkton', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/sk-33_metric_e.html'),

            #MANITOBA CITIES

            city('Winnipeg', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-38_metric_e.html'),
            city('Sprague', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/mb-23_metric_e.html'),

            #ONTARIO CITIES

            city('Thunder Bay', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-100_metric_e.html'),
            city('Sioux Lookout', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-135_metric_e.html'),
            city('Armstrong', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-111_metric_e.html'),
            city('Hornepayne', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-78_metric_e.html'),
            city('Sudbury', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-40_metric_e.html'),
            city('South Parry', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-103_metric_e.html'),
            city('Toronto', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-143_metric_e.html'),
            city('Kingston', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-69_metric_e.html'),
            city('Cornwall', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-152_metric_e.html'),
            city('Sarnia', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-147_metric_e.html'),

            #QUEBEC CITIES

            city('Montreal', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/qc-147_metric_e.html'),
            city('Quebec', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/qc-133_metric_e.html'),
            city('La Tuque', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/qc-154_metric_e.html'),
            city('Saguenay', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/qc-166_metric_e.html'),
            city('Riviere-du-loup', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/qc-108_metric_e.html'),

            #NOVA SCOTIA CITIES

            city('Truro', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ns-25_metric_e.html'),
            city('Halifax', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/ns-19_metric_e.html'),

            #NEW BRUNSWICK CITIES

            city('Edmundston', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/nb-32_metric_e.html'),
            city('Moncton', 'http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/nb-36_metric_e.html'),
        ]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What determines what line a given city's data should be written to? If there's no way to know that, there's no way to solve this problem.

Comment: I am importing to a base excel spreadsheet and every city has its own assigned row. I just only showed a couple of cities and their respective rows, but they are all pre-determined.

Comment: So is the city going to the row "random" as you say or now they are predetermined? You are being contradictory

Comment: @RyanSaxe - Ah, yes, sorry about the confusion. They are all predetermined. This initial text has been updated to clarify.

Comment: In order to send them to the correct rows, you need to be given a set if criteria. That is what @Blckknght was saying

Comment: That is why I said I need to send the "first city in the loop to row1, the data from the second city to row 3, the data from the third city to row 6, etc..." I just assumed I could extrapolate from whatever someone might come up with for those 3 cities. Is that not correct?

Comment: that doesn't make sense. If it is all predetermined how do you know anything. Your row # examples don't really say much

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37614/discussion-between-hunter21188-and-ryan-saxe)

Comment: For future reference, it would probably be much easier to get an answer if you simplified your code to just a few lines. (ie make a SSCE)